# I'm trying to loop a list and unable to add it to the string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, split

For example, I do have a code like below, where

```
res = get_prediction_eos(input_text)
print("res is : ", res)

answer = []

print("res ", res['bert'].split("\n"))

for i in res['bert'].split("\n"):
     answer.append(i)
answer_as_string = "    ".join(answer)

print("answer is : ", answer_as_string)
```

And the output for the above code is returned as below :

```
res is :  {'bert': 'up\nwrong\nhappening\nnew\nhappened'}
res  ['up', 'wrong', 'happening', 'new', 'happened']
answer is :  up    wrong    happening    new    happened
```

I do have a text like below code :

```
text = "Hey what's"
```

**The main required output is 'answer is :  up    wrong    happening    new    happened'. I  do have a text like 'Hey what's' and i want to add the answer's outputs to the text like**

```
Hey what's up
Hey what's wrong
Hey what's happening
Hey what's new
Hey what's happened
```

Can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: What's exactly the issue you're facing in the `answer_as_string`? Is it just that you need to use single space " " with `.join()` instead of 4 spaces? 
Also, for your text part, you can simply output those "Hey what's ..." strings with a for-loop as:
`for word in answer: print(text + " " + word)`
Or store it in a new variable, if that's what you want

Comment: Yes, this worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to iterate over the list and print text + the element in the loop.

In Python >= 3.6:

```
for e in res['bert'].split('\n'):
    print(f'{text} {e}?')
```